# Orthogonal Basis for a 4x3 matrix confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a bit of trouble with a question on my Linear Algebra summer exam. I passed so it's all good but there was a question on it that has been bothering me. The question is, find an orthonormal basis $\left\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3}\right\}$ of the image of the linear function given by the matrix $$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&2\\
-1&0&0\\
-1&0&1\\
0&1&1 \end{array}\right)$$
Which is fine but then the question asks to find $a_2$ such that $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&2\\
-1&0&0\\
-1&0&1\\
0&1&1 \end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1\end{array}\right)=a_1\vec{v_1}+a_2\vec{v_2}+a_3\vec{v_3}$, what I don't understand is that since $A$ is a 4x3 matrix then the vectors in the basis of its image should have 3 components but for the second part shouldn't the vectors have four components?

Comment: What is the orthonormal basis of a map? Are you sure it shouldn't be "orthonormal basis of the image"?

Comment: Your computation yields $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4$.  However, the dimension of the row space of that matrix is $3$.  Therefore, $v_4$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2$, and $v_3$.

Comment: The image of A is its column space, which is a subspace of $R^4$, so the vectors in the image of A should have 4 components.